# Running R script with subprocess on Windows, subprocess seems missing

Tags: python, r, windows, powershell, subprocess

I am using python on windows.
I want to call an R script in my python code.

My script R is :

```
c <- 3
print(paste("hello", c))
```

My python code calls the Rscript like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['Rscript', "sb.R"])
```

Unfortunately I have this error message :

```
File "C:\Users\[...]\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 557, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\[...]\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\[...]\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The file is not found
```

I have checked the following:

1) under powershell, when I enter `Rscript .\sb.R` it works.

2) in the python code I tried

```
theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "sbpy.py"])
theproc.communicate()
```

where sbpy.py contains `print("hello py")`. This works as well. So I assume that the library subprocess do work.

3) I tried the following code :

```
cmd = ['Rscript', 'sb.R']
x = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

I have then the following error :

```
...
  File "C:\Users\[...]\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['Rscript', 'sb.R']' returned non-zero e
xit status 1
```

4) As for the path, I have checked and yes R folder is in my path.

I newly installed python35 on my windows machine, is it a file missing in the lib subprocess, or is it something I have missed?

Comment: It can't find a file named "Rscript" or "Rscript.exe" in the application, system, current, and `PATH` directories.

Comment: So I did edit my question.
It appears that it does not find Rscript. I have checked the path and it is. Also, in powershell the command `Rscript .\sb.R` does work.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that PowerShell finds a file named "Rscript" or "Rscript.exe". It also looks for the name plus extensions from the `PathExt` environment variable. Run `where.exe Rscript` to look for it.

Comment: Also, since you know where R is installed, try `where.exe /r [R installation path] Rscript` to recursively search its folder for files named Rscript, Rscript.exe, etc.

Comment: So I put the entire path in the command, and yes it works.
Doing what you say implies that on any computer I run, I should either add the R package to my ressources then know the path to it, or first find on the computer?
So is this a finite solution or just a temporary one just to make my code works?

Comment: Append the directory that contains Rscript.exe to the `PATH` environment variable in the Windows environment-variable editor. Then start a new cmd.exe, powershell.exe, or python.exe instance from Explorer (by icon or win+r command line) to get the updated `PATH` value.

Comment: @eryksun, can you write that as an answer so that I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your python script and Rscript in are the same file location.

Example: 
       Create a file named sb.R and subprocess_demo.py under Desktop location.
       Change directory to Desktop in command prompt and run following command 
       **python subprocess_demo.py**

***sb.R***

```
c <- 3
print(paste("hello", c))
```

***subprocess_demo.py***

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['Rscript', "sb.R"])
```

Comment: The error is from within Python, from the `CreateProcess` call (called by `subprocess.Popen`) not being able to find rscript.exe. It's not related to finding "sb.R". Also, a relative path is resolved against the process working directory, which the rscript.exe child process inherits, and which has nothing to do with the directory of the Python script. The working directory, application directory (location of python.exe), and script directory have no relation to each other.